# Поведение XMLHttpRequest в Qml при отключении интернета (запрос к localhost)

Tags: qt, xmlhttprequest, qml

Имеется XMLHttpRequest на сервер расположенный по адресу **localhost:port** (http://127.0.0.1:port/)

При удачном (правильном) get запросе сервер возвращает ответ в виде:

```
{
    "meta": {
     "code": <code>
    },
...
}
```

Если такая команда на сервере отсутствует, code = 404.
В случае успешного обращения, code = 200.

1. Обращение к серверу при подключенном интернете проходит отлично.
2. Обращение к серверу при отключенном интернете проходит, также, отлично (приложение было запущено после отключения интернета).
3. Если при запуске приложения присутствовал интернет и все запросы к серверу отлично проходили, то после обрыва интернета (и физически - отключение сетевого кабеля, и программно - отключение сетевого интерфейса) перестают проходить запросы на локальный сервер.

Пример кода:

```js
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true

    property int it: 0

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 1000
        onTriggered: it++;
        repeat: true

    }

    onItChanged: {
        if(it>=5) {
            sendCommand()
            it = 0
        }
    }

    function sendCommand() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        timer.running = false;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            timer.running = true;
            if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
                console.debug('HEADERS_RECEIVED');
            } else if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                var object = JSON.parse(request.responseText.toString());
                console.debug('DONE');
                console.debug(JSON.stringify(object, null, 2));
            }
        }

        request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:13112/GetCloseTime', false);
        request.send(null);
    }

    Component.onCompleted: timer.start();
}
```

Вывод в консоль до обрыва интернета:

```
qml: HEADERS_RECEIVED
qml: DONE
qml: {
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "task": "None",
  "time": {
    "hours": 20,
    "minutes": 0
  }
}
```

После обрыва:

```
qrc:/main.qml:34: JSON.parse: Parse error
```

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с такой проблемой или есть ли мыли как ее обойти?

Comment: Использован комплект Qt 5.6.0 MSVC2013 32bit

Comment: Ну так может отпечатаете в консоль request.responseText перед парсингом?

Comment: @andreymal     если выводить request.responseText перед парсингом, то при подключенном интернете получаем {"meta": {"code": 200}, "task": "None", "time": {"hours":20, "minutes":0 } } - собственно полный и верный ответ. А при обрыве выводится пустая строка.   Проверил в Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2013 32bit - результат тотже.